# JWPLayer cross-browser issue when use idangerous.swiper

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I'm using JWPLayer in conjuction with a jQuery plugin, called idangero.us.swiper. The problem is that it works well in FF, but not in Chrome and IE with this code.

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "Wildlife.flv",
        image: "Penguins.jpg",
        width: 560,
        height: 300
  });
      var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        pagination: '.pagination',
        loop:true,
        grabCursor: true,
        paginationClickable: true, 
        useCSS3Transforms: false
      })
      $('.arrow-left').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        mySwiper.swipePrev();
      })
      $('.arrow-right').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        mySwiper.swipeNext();
      })
```

With code in which I comment out mySwiper code this code makes it run on Chrome. So problem lies in using Swiper code. Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong with it?

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "Wildlife.flv",
        image: "Penguins.jpg",
        width: 560,
        height: 300
  });
      /*var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
        pagination: '.pagination',
        loop:true,
        grabCursor: true,
        paginationClickable: true, 
        useCSS3Transforms: false
      })
      $('.arrow-left').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        mySwiper.swipePrev();
      })
      $('.arrow-right').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        mySwiper.swipeNext();
      })*/
```

**Update**: In Chrome's console it says following error,

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://api.a-tu-zi.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://imooviz.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.`

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are running this....

Comment: Here is the link @EthanJWPlayer : imooviz.com/JWPLAYER/jwplayer.html

Comment: Can you update your player from 6.1 to 6.8? - https://account.jwplayer.com/

Comment: Okay let me try. Thank you

Comment: http://imooviz.com/JWPLAYER/jwplayer.html is still 6.1.

Comment: no sir, i abandoned.